# Carousel with links not clickable, clicks previous link instead

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.carousel_lb {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 26px;
}

.carousel_lb-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel_lb-open:checked + .carousel_lb-item {
    position: static;
    opacity: 100;
}

.carousel_lb-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.carousel_lb-item img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel_lb-control {
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #242627;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel_lb-control.prev {
    left: -50px;
}

.carousel_lb-control.next {
    right: -50px;
}

.carousel_lb-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel_lb-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel_lb-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel_lb-3:checked ~ .control-3,
#carousel_lb-4:checked ~ .control-4,
#carousel_lb-5:checked ~ .control-5,
#carousel_lb-6:checked ~ .control-6,
#carousel_lb-7:checked ~ .control-7,
#carousel_lb-8:checked ~ .control-8,
#carousel_lb-9:checked ~ .control-9,
#carousel_lb-10:checked ~ .control-10 {
    display: block;
}

.carousel_lb-indicators {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel_lb-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel_lb-bullet {
    color: #fbd4ca;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel_lb-bullet:hover {
    color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel_lb-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel_lb-bullet,
#carousel_lb-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel_lb-bullet,
#carousel_lb-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel_lb-bullet,
#carousel_lb-4:checked ~ .control-4 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(4) .carousel_lb-bullet,
#carousel_lb-5:checked ~ .control-5 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(5) .carousel_lb-bullet,
#carousel_lb-6:checked ~ .control-6 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(6) .carousel_lb-bullet,
#carousel_lb-7:checked ~ .control-7 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(7) .carousel_lb-bullet,
#carousel_lb-8:checked ~ .control-8 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(8) .carousel_lb-bullet,
#carousel_lb-9:checked ~ .control-9 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(9) .carousel_lb-bullet,
#carousel_lb-10:checked ~ .control-10 ~ .carousel_lb-indicators li:nth-child(10) .carousel_lb-bullet {
    color: #428bca;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
    .only-desktop {
        display: none !important;
    }
    #lastcomments {
        margin: auto !important;
    }
    .carousel_lb-control.prev {
        left: 5px;
    }
    .carousel_lb-control.next {
        right: 5px;
    }

}

</style>
<div class="carousel_lb">
    <div class="carousel_lb-inner">
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-1" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link1</a>
        </div>
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-2" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link2</a>
        </div>
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-3" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link3</a>
        </div>
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-4" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link4</a>
        </div>
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-5" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link5</a>
        </div>
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-6" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link6</a>
        </div>
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-7" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link7</a>
        </div>
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-8" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link8</a>
        </div>
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-9" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link9</a>
        </div>
        <input class="carousel_lb-open" type="radio" id="carousel_lb-10" name="carousel_lb" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel_lb-item">
            <a href="...">Link10</a>
        </div>
        <label for="carousel_lb-10" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-1">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-2" class="carousel_lb-control next control-1">›</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-1" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-2">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-3" class="carousel_lb-control next control-2">›</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-2" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-3">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-4" class="carousel_lb-control next control-3">›</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-3" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-4">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-5" class="carousel_lb-control next control-4">›</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-4" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-5">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-6" class="carousel_lb-control next control-5">›</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-5" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-6">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-7" class="carousel_lb-control next control-6">›</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-6" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-7">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-8" class="carousel_lb-control next control-7">›</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-7" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-8">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-9" class="carousel_lb-control next control-8">›</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-8" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-9">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-10" class="carousel_lb-control next control-9">›</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-9" class="carousel_lb-control prev control-10">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel_lb-1" class="carousel_lb-control next control-10">›</label>
        <ol class="carousel_lb-indicators">
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-1" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-2" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-3" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-4" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-5" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-6" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-7" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-8" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-9" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="carousel_lb-10" class="carousel_lb-bullet">•</label>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code I'm trying to show some elements with a background photo and links (inside .carousel_lb-item). First elements on the carousel are working fine, the others seem fine but their links are not clickable, instead of them, previous element's link is on top actually. For example, when I click Link2, it actually clicks the Link1, it clicks Link4 when I try to click Link5, and so on. I guess there is a problem with displays and opacities, but couldn't make it work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are closing your links with `<a/>` instead of `</a>`, I think the browser is probably trying to fix the un-closed element for you and each link is becoming nested in the previous one.

Comment: actually it's not what's there on real code, I just put it to simplify the situation.I corrected them. I checked and they are </a> on the real code, so I still have the problem. any other suggestions?